# Boolean methods return expression is not showing the result in output console

Tags: java, methods, boolean, boolean-expression

The code is written to display whether isTeen is True/False.
the below code is giving the correct output. but, then it's not printing in the IntelliJ output console.

```
public static boolean hasTeen(int age1, int age2, int age3) {
    if ((age1 >= 13 && age1 <= 19) || (age2 >= 13 && age2 <= 19) || (age3 >= 13 && age3 <= 19)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isTeen(int age1) {
    if (age1 >= 13 && age1 <= 19) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

I would expect to display TRUE/FALSE based on the input given. but, nothing printed.

Comment: don't expect us to visit outside links. post all relevant information and a clear description of the issue in your question.

Comment: What output would you expect? What you see in the console is the exit code of your program. This has nothing to do with an program output but indicates whether your program was executed successfully. In general exit code != 0 indicate errors

Comment: What output are you expecting? You are not creating any output in your code.

Comment: It should be printed True/ false based on the given input Right?

Comment: Where do you think it will be printed? Can you tell where in your code is print method or anything that prints?

Comment: You never actually do anything with the return value of your methods. To do so, you could save the return value in a boolean like: `boolean retVal = isTeen(15);` and after that print the result to your console like `System.out.println(retVal);`. Then you can see what was actually returned. Or you skip one step if you don't need the value to be saved and simply use `System.out.println(isTeen(15));`.

Comment: @Vetrivel your isTeen(int age) method can be rewritten to: public static boolean isTeen(int age) { return (age1 >= 13 && age1 <= 19); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.out.println()` to print output on the console.

**Edit**
In your case, your main method would look as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(hasTeen(13,42,45));
    System.out.println(isTeen(19));
    System.out.println(isTeen(29));
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(hasTeen(13,42,45)); - this helps me to print the Boolean return expressions. thanks @Dhiral Kaniya

Answer (score 0):

It is returning but you are not Catching the result.
Try this once

```
 System.out.println(hasTeen(13,42,45));
 System.out.println(isTeen(19));
 System.out.println(isTeen(25));
```